# How do I add auto-suggested locations?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places

see rightmove.co.uk

it has the box at the top and you begin typing a city, town, postcode, area location whatever and it auto suggests it. It also seems to have every place in the UK and I am guessing every place in the world.

How does this work? Not so much the auto suggest part (I am guessing that is some javascript) but I do want to know this too, but mainly how they have every place in the UK like that. Is that manually added or is it done using google web developer tools and linked to google maps? Is it Google Places? How easy is it to add? I have a property website which I want to add it to.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/

it's most likely using Google places API, it uses the same database as Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably using one of the datasets from Ordnance Survey, to power this rather than Google, as they do not show a Google logo on the interface.

There is an open dataset called [OS Open Names](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/os-open-names.html), which contains Place names, road numbers and postcodes for the UK.

If you don't want to use the Google Places API, you could load this dataset into a database and set up an auto suggest API around it.